# Manifolds as Cauchy completed objects

Tags: ct.category-theory, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

The category of smooth manifolds (SmoothMfld) can be thought of the Cauchy completion of the category $U$ of open subsets of Euclidean spaces (with smooth maps) [1]. This fact is shocking to me as it provides an **intrinsic** definition of smooth manifolds.

If this fact can be generalized to manifolds equipped with other types of structures, we'd have a whole new perspective of what a manifold ought to be.

Alas, the proof given in [1] only works for smooth manifolds: Modulo some categoricaly nonsense, the crux of the proof (given in [1]) lies in the fact that the fixed point set of any idempotent in $U$ again has a smooth manifold structure. This essentially requires the use of tangent space and, more importantly, the inverse function theorem

Still, it doesn't prove that it fails for other cases. Thus this question: **Is the category (X-Mfld) the Cauchy completion of the corresponding $U$**, for X being Topological, PiecewiseLinear, Complex, Analytic.. etc?

**Reference**

[1] nLab authors, "[chapter 4: The category of smooth manifolds](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/revision/Karoubi%20envelope/35#the_category_of_smooth_manifolds)", [*Karoubi envelope* (Revision 35)](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/revision/Karoubi%20envelope/35), August 2022.

Comment: I don't know the history, but I'd suspect that the fact that you mention was part of the *motivation* for the definition of the Cauchy completion of a category, or at least a prominent test case.  That is, to speak poetically, the concept is not an elegant container into which manifolds happen coincidentally to fit, but rather an elegant container purpose-made to hold manifolds (among other things).  Of course that doesn't mean it's not profitable to examine it further!

Comment: @LSpice I'm less confident about the history: I have seen Karoubi envelopes (or idempotent completions) used quite often in representation theory and category theory, where they are a very natural construction-- but I had no idea about this fact about manifolds.  However, I would say this characterization of smooth manifolds seems more "extrinsic" than "intrinsic", because it really boils down to the Whitney embedding and tubular neighborhood theorems.  (I.e. you are presenting the smooth manifolds by embedding them in R^n).

Comment: @PhilTosteson that's the proof, which inevitably must use extrinsic tools as we start with the extrinsic (i.e. traditional) definition. However, if we only focus on the end result, it is very intrinsic. (And yeah, such constructions show up in module theories and condensations often).

Comment: @PhilTosteson, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429003/manifolds-as-cauchy-completed-objects#comment1103548_429003), I'm quite willing to believe my speculation went amiss.  It seems strange to call the process something so Euclidean-flavoured if that's not what's on your mind—but I'd never even previously encountered the concept, and so shouldn't pretend to any expertise.  (Anyway, let me emphasise that the question seems worthwhile, whatever the history.)

Comment: @LSpice That's a good point-- I think the different names for the construction might reflect different (parallel) histories of the concept.  Apparently the term Cauchy completion was introduced by Lawvere.

Comment: I think the answer should be "no" for Topological, PL, and complex analytic manifolds.   In the PL and topological cases,  the presheaf associated to the idempotent that retracts $\mathbb R^2$ onto the coordinate axes should yield an object of the Cauchy completion which is not represented by a manifold.  In the complex analytic case,  compact complex analytic manifolds cannot be embedded into $\mathbb C^n$, so they should not be representable by an idempotent.

Comment: @PhilTosteson: Your last comment seems like a clear answer to the question — may I suggest making it into an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Thanks, I didn't write an answer b/c I haven't actually proved that the objects I mentioned aren't in the categories.  If you've thought it through, feel free to make an answer.

Comment: Another counterexample for the PL case is a manifold with boundary. The closed interval is a retract of an open interval.

Comment: @PhilTosteson: OK, I’ve made it an answer (though there’s not much to prove beyond your suggestions!)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

(Expanding on Phil Tosteson’s [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429003/manifolds-as-cauchy-completed-objects#comment1103552_429003).)  **No: the Cauchy-completion characterisation doesn’t hold for the PL, topological, or complex-analytic cases.**

The key technical point is that split idempotents are always *absolute*, i.e. preserved by all functors, in particular the forgetful functor to $\mathrm{Top}$.  This says that any splitting of an idempotent must be precisely (up to iso) the subspace of fixpoints, as you’d expect.

With this in hand, it’s easy to check that **in the PL and topological categories, the subspace of fixpoints of an idempotent isn’t generally a manifold, so the category of manifolds isn’t Cauchy-complete**.  Take for instance the PL idempotent retracting $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\R^2$ onto the lines $x = \pm y$, sending $(x,y)$ to $\min(\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|)(\newcommand{\sg}{\operatorname{sg}}\sg(x),\sg(y))$ (where $\sg(x)$ denotes the sign of $x$, in $\{1,-1\}$).

Contrariwise, **in the complex-analytic category, not every manifold arises as the splitting of an idempotent**, since not every complex manifold embeds into some $\mathbb{C}^n$.  For example, connected compact complex manifolds have no nonconstant holomorphic functions to $\mathbb{C}$; this follows easily from the maximum modulus principle.